# install @auth0/angular-jwt causes an error in several references, as if it were incompatible. Angular 14

Tags: angular, angular14

After installing **@auth0/angular-jwt** the project gives error in several references, as shown in the image below. I'm using Angular 14.

After installation I ran the commands and nothing.
ng update
npm cache clean --force

If I uninstall the package, the project works correctly again.

**Errors and Project dependencies**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **[Solved]**

**Steps taken for the solution:**

1. Delete directory: ".angular"
2. Delete directory: "node_modules"
3. Run command: npm install @angular-devkit/schematics
4. Run command: ng update
5. Run command: npm uninstall @angular-devkit/schematics
6. Run command: ng build